# Determine the polygon side with given inner angle

Tags: java, javafx

I made the following picture to help visualize the problem:

[image]

You can control the monkey, by rotating it. You can step to the neigbour fields, but here I have a problem calculating which is the field to step.

The monkey has an angle, which goes from 0 to 360 degress, 0 is when its head is up. I would like to calculate the neigbour field from this angle. (Basically this field is where the orangutan "looks").
I store the neigbours, and also the vertices for every polygon.

I tried with the following idea:

Start a half line from the orangutan, then calculate the intersection with each side of the polygon. If we have an intersection, then we know the two endpoints. Then search through the neigbour fields, if one of them has both points in its vertices, then this is the good one.

[image: Equations]

Here the code I wrote:

```java
public Field getNeighbourByAngle(double angle) {
        // Field center
        Point2D c = center;

        // New point initial coordinates
        double x = c.getX(); double y = c.getY()+1;

        // Rotate the point by the angle
        Point2D rotatedPoint = new Point2D(
                -(x*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) - y*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))), 
                y*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) + x*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))  );

        // Get the vector from the center to the roteted point
        Point2D v = rotatedPoint.subtract(c);

        // Iterate over the vertex arraylist
        for (int i = 0; i<verts.size(); i++) {
            // Get the two endpoints
            Point2D p1 = verts.get(i);
            Point2D p2;
            if (i == verts.size() - 1) {
                p2 = verts.get(0); 
            } else { p2 = verts.get(i+1);}

            // Calculate the intersection
            // Using the formula:
            //  x = c.x + v.x * t
            //  x = p1.x * (1-t) + p2.x * t
            // These two are equals, get t from the equation:
            double t = ( p1.getX() - c.getX( )) / (v.getX() + p1.getX() - p2.getX() );

            // t has to be between [0, 1] because p1 <-> p2 is just a line segment
            if (0 <= t && t<= 1) {
                // Iterate over the neigbours
                for (int j = 0; j<neighbours.size(); j++) {
                    // If the neigbour has both p1 and p2 in its vertices list, then we found the correct neigbour.
                    if (neighbours.get(j).getVerts().contains(p1) && 
                        neighbours.get(j).getVerts().contains(p2)) {
                        return neighbours.get(j);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

But I not get the correct results, I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: You made an mistake in your math equations. You forgot to take into account that the parameter `t` need not be identical for both lines. You should better write `x = center.x + v.x * t1` and `x = p1.x * t2 + p2.x * (1 - t2)`. `p1.x * t2 + p2.x * (1 - t2) = center.x + v.x * t1` and it's equivalent for the y coordinate can be rewritten to provide you with an equation system with 2 equations and 2 unknown variables which can be solved for `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: I think there is an easier way to approach this though: minimize the angle between the vector and the vector to the vertices to find one of the vertices of the intersected edge.This can be done by finding the maximum cosine which can be found using [the dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):maximize `v*(p-c)/(|v|*|p-c|)`. You can determine the other vertex by checking, which one of the neighboring vertices is on the same side of the line `c+v*t` (rotate `v` by 90° to get `v'` and `(p-c) * v'` should differ in sign for the vertices of the edge). (No edge cases considered yet.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to solve it with your second suggestion. (with a slight modification, but the same idea). 
Probably the main problem was that javafx y-axis is pointing downwards, so there was a bit of miscalculation. I implemented your solution, than corrected the axis problem. Your idea was lot simpler than mine, so thank you very much. How can I accept your solution?